# Making border with QuartzCore is slow?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, quartz-core

When i try to do a border to a view my view become slow

```
[self.userView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.userView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[self.userView.layer setCornerRadius:15.0f];
[self.userView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
[self.userView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to set the `shouldRasterize` property of your layer to `YES`.

Comment: Terrible solution, it makes it ugly

Comment: @Tom Perfect solution actually, rasterisation is the only way to optimise performance in this case. See my answer on how to improve the quality.

Answer (score 1):

This is a follow on from omz's answer to improve the quality of the rasterised layer, to prevent pixelation you need to set the rasterisation scale too.

```
[self.userView.layer setShouldRaterize:YES];
[self.userView.layer setRasterizationScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];
```